# UpdateAsync not Working for Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to update a row in a Windows Azure Mobile Services Database with a .NET client using the following code:

```
List<TodoItem> myItemsList = await todoTable.Where(todoItem => todoItem.XID == 1).ToListAsync();
TodoItem myItem = myItemsList.First();
myItem.TITLE = "New Title";
await myClient.GetTable<TodoItem>().UpdateAsync(myItem);
```

The XID attribute is just my own integer key that I've added, different to the required guid. The problem is the update isn't going through. Some things to note are:

- The retrieval part works fine when I'm debugging it.  Locally the TITLE attribute gets set to "New Title" correctly, but when the UpdateAsync command gets executed and I mouse-over the 'myItem' instance I see the TITLE attribute has reverted back to its original value.
- I corrupted the guid when testing the code, and the UpdateAsync failed as expected, since there is no record in my table with that guid.
- I'm pretty sure this code was working before, now it's not.

For now I'm making do with running the DeleteAsync command, followed by the InsertAsync and that does the trick. But I'm baffled as to why the UpdateAsync command isn't working for me, and why when it does execute it refreshes the 'myItem' instance with the original data.

Comment: If you're using the JS backend, do you have any scripts for the update operation in the server side? If using the .NET backend, can you post the definition of the PatchTodoItem operation in your controller?

Comment: It's .NET backend. I didn't touch much of the code in this - just used the standard ToDoItem example. Here's the PatchToDoItem operation: 
        `public Task<TodoItem> PatchTodoItem(string id, Delta<TodoItem> patch)
        {
            return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
        }`

Comment: Try debugging the .NET backend (either by running locally or attaching a debugger to your running instance by selecting your service in Server Explorer). Is the correct value being sent to the backend?  I also recommend using a tool like Fiddler to see what HTTP request is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure at all but if you are desperate try to change : 
(no reputation for comment)

`List<TodoItem> myItemsList = await todoTable.Where(todoItem => todoItem.XID == 1).ToListAsync();
TodoItem myItem = myItemsList.First();`

to :

`TodoItem myItem = todoTable.Where(todoItem => todoItem.XID == 1).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: I tried that - didn't work. Also 'FirstOrDefault()' needs to be applied as follows `myItemsList.FirstOrDefault()`. It can't be applied as you had it. Thanks though for the suggestion.

Comment: My point here is to not cast on List your data and leave it as Queryable. 
Try to bypass this ToListAsync()